# Click on button in MainActivity and go to screen on MainActivity2

Tags: android, button, click

me as a noob in Android programming, I don't get it, too many solutions, examples, I am too frustrated.

I have MainActivity and MainActivity2
and for each one i have, activity_main.xml and activity_main2.xml

In activity_main.xml in graphical layout I added a button, I want to click on it and to go on MainActivity2, to view activity_main2.xml screen.

Who can help me with a working example. I cant figure it out :(

Comment: There are countless tutorials, try something first, then come here.

Comment: Try this out that might be a start http://android.mayuonline.com/2011/05/20/passing-data-with-intent/

Comment: Refer this example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/ Let me know, if you stil has the problem.

Comment: You really gotta get your basic understanding in order before you ask questions like these.
Go to: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html and follow the trail. If you can't wait to find out how to open one activity from another jump directly to this spot: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
Also it annoys me that people just throws answers at you, that you won't even understand, because you're missing the basic understanding of Android in the first place.

Comment: Here's a tutorial for complete begineers. http://tekeye.biz/2012/starting-a-second-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onCreate method, you should do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class));
        }

    }
}
```

The `your_button_id` is the ID of the button in your `MainActivity` and the code above tells the button to `startActivity` when the button is pressed. In this case, the new activity is `MainActivity2`.

For more information, you should go through the tutorials available: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest you to take a look at [these video tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6) by Travis. They are pretty useful, well structured and easy to understand, a good start for any beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Intend to call another Activity.
and  in Manifest, you have to add your second activity.

**In First Activity**

```
 Button btListe = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Liste);
    btListe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   
        }
    });
```

**TUTORIAL** If You looking for tutorial [see here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1525).

Answer (score 0):

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Go to Activity Two"
   android:id="@+id/btnActTwo">
  </Button>
  </LinearLayout>
```

activity_two:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="This is Activity Two">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button btnActTwo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActTwo);
    btnActTwo.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnActTwo:
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, ActivityTwo.class);
        startActivity (intent);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

ActivityTwo:

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_two);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank You Very much, but I have some errors: in MainActivity.java  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   it asks me to change activity_main  to activity_list_item